# Использовать composer Для создания нового проекта на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer

У меня установлен локальный сервер  Xampp ,  в папке  htdocs я уже создал проект на  Laravel ,все правильно работает, но я хочу создать  совершенно новый проект в той же папке,  нужны  ли тогда какие то изменения  к командам  для composer,  учитывая что у меня уже установлен Laravel  ?

Answer (score 1):

Да. Для каждого проекта нужно выполнять команду

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog

где - blog имя папки-проекта которую создаст Composer

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel** устанавливается в виде пакетов посредством пакетного менеджера **Composer**. Больше ничего не делается, далее вы уже работаете с фреймворком как с обычными скритам, поэтому если вы хотите в туже папку сделать новый проект, то переименуйте папку или удалите её вовсе и **начинайте снова как описано в документации**.